# Calculate length of string with only spaces in Unix for a fixed width file

Tags: unix, fixed

I am having a fixed width file created via a BTEQ script in Unix. I am able to calculate the length correctly for all fields until the field which has some value.

In BTEQ script:

```
SELECT RPAD(COALESCE(SSO_ID,''),50,' ')||
RPAD(COALESCE(GENERIC4,''),100,' ')||
RPAD(COALESCE(GENERIC5,''),100,' ')||
RPAD(COALESCE(GENERIC6,''),100,' ')||
RPAD(COALESCE(GENERIC7,''),100,' ')||
RPAD(COALESCE(GENERIC8,''),100,' ')||
RPAD(COALESCE(GENERIC9,''),100,' ')||
RPAD(COALESCE(GENERIC10,''),100,' ')
FROM <view_name>
```

FILENM is an output file created via the above BTEQ script:

```
LENGTH_SSO_ID=`cat  $FILENM | grep 57080249 |cut -c1361-1410| tr " " "~" | wc -c`
LENGTH_GENERIC4=`cat  $FILENM | grep 57080249 |cut -c1711-1810| tr " " "~" | wc -c`
LENGTH_GENERIC5=`cat  $FILENM | grep 57080249 cut -c1811-1910| tr " " "~" | wc -c`
LENGTH_GENERIC6=`cat  $FILENM | grep 57080249 cut -c1911-2010| tr " " "~" | wc -c`
LENGTH_GENERIC7=`cat  $FILENM | grep 57080249 cut -c2011-2110| tr " " "~" | wc -c`
LENGTH_GENERIC8=`cat  $FILENM | grep 57080249 cut -c2111-2210| tr " " "~" | wc -c`
LENGTH_GENERIC9=`cat  $FILENM | grep 57080249 |cut -c2211-2310| tr " " "~" | wc -c`
LENGTH_GENERIC10=`cat  $FILENM | grep 57080249 |cut -c2311-2410| tr " " "~" | wc -c`
```

This is output I'm getting, where ideally I should get 100 length each for GENERIC columns.

```
LENGTH of SSO_ID=50
LENGTH of GENERIC4=5
LENGTH of GENERIC5=0
LENGTH of GENERIC6=0
LENGTH of GENERIC7=0
LENGTH of GENERIC8=0
LENGTH of GENERIC9=0
LENGTH of GENERIC10=0
```

Please advise why it is giving the incorrect length for columns which have spaces always and occur at the end of the record.

Comment: Include a sample output from your BTEQ script

Comment: >cat test.ksh
Name|Class|School Name
Deepu|First|Meridian
Neethu|Second|Meridian
Sethu|First|DAV
Theekshana|Second|DAV
Teju|First|Sangamithra

>export LEN=`cat test.ksh | grep Neethu | cut -c1-6 | tr " " "~" | wc -c`
>$ echo $LEN
7

Comment: I don't understand. Your BTEQ scripts seems to make lines of 750 kength, you are trying to get positions 2311-2410 from some lines and your output shows that the linelength is 1716. And some statements are missing `|` before the `cut`.

Comment: actually thats a small snipped from my code..actual cut starts from cut -c1-1